# iphone consume wcf once every minute

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

My app is able to consume a wcf using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). But the thing is that i need to check the server hour every one minute. So i need a request to the server every one minute. What is more, sometime i will need to refresh the clock every one second.

the app is a items auction so i need to get the hour no matter what.

so my question is, is this going to kill the iphone?
[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) have a method to achieve this? making calls every XX time?
some good way to do it?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data you are getting back isn't larger than the memory threshold, and you are properly managing memory on your end, AND you are performing an asynchronous request (or a request on a background thread), this shouldn't kill the app memory-wise or cause it to hang.

I do something similar, where every 2 minutes I ping my server for updates.  I achieve this using an [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html), though I imagine ASIHTTPRequest is not much different.  I typically use a [recurring timer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) that, when invoked, calls a method which, using [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html), sets up my request/connection and fires.